# Android - Test Pending Purchases with Subscriptions

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, in-app-billing, subscription

I am trying to test pending purchases on Android for my app which is going to have subscriptions. At the moment I see:

1. Test card always approves.
2. Test card always declines.

I need to see:

1. Test card slow to approve.
2. Test card slow to decline.

How can I see these payment instruments when making a test purchase?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pending purchases currently work only for one time items, not subscriptions: [docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#pending)

Comment: Does this mean that subscriptions do not have pending purchases or that they cannot be tested with subscriptions. I find it odd that a requirement requested by Google cannot be tested!

Comment: Yes, subscriptions do not have pending purchases, so it's not possible to test them. You can only test pending purchases for one time items.